# Regex-match everything and stop at

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match everything up to a key phrase using regex.  Basically, it's looking at an email, I want it to return everything before the conversation history.

I've been trying to use `(?:^|\W)From:(?:$|\W)([A-Z][a-z]*)[\s-]([A-Z][a-z]*)` to stop at `From: Dave Patel` (in the example below) and match everything before.

Example text below, whenever I search I am only able to return the preceding line or two.

```
This is just some test text.

Many thanks,

James Jones
Some company
51 made up street
The world

From: Dave Patel 
Sent: 08 December 2017 14:57
To: Clare Jones <Clare.Jones.com>; Paul Smith <paul.smith@company.com>
Subject: Re: Files

Well done!  Let me know when implemented if you want me to test.

From: Dave Patel 
Sent: 08 December 2017 14:57
To: Clare Jones <Clare.Jones.com>; Paul Smith <paul.smith@company.com>
Subject: Re: Files

The fox jumps over the lazy dog

Joseph Smith
```

A company 
bla bla
blaaaa

Comment: `(.*?)From:` in dot all mode should work, with what you want being made available in the first capture group.  What tool/language are you using here?

Comment: What are you trying to search with? A programming language? A text editor? There are different "flavours" of regex, so it's best to include information about the full context of your problem.

Comment: A single regex is going to result in a lot of false positives. Anything in tabular format like "your password: xyzzy" or "order: 23 platinum-plated monocles" is going to match a reasonably general regex.

Comment: The proper solution, of course, is to sell as slaves to Africa anyone who formats their emails like that.

Comment: `(.*?)^From: ([A-Z][a-z]*)[\s-]([A-Z][a-z]*)`? I'm not exactly sure what your expected output is...

Comment: Please specify programming language

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
(.*?)From:(?:$|\W)([A-Z][a-z]*)[\s-]([A-Z][a-z]*)
```

I think Group 1 from the result of this regex is what you are looking for.

From you example, Group 1 will be:

```
This is just some test text.

Many thanks,

James Jones
Some company
51 made up street
The world
```